# jQuery form doesn't submit after correcting failing validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a simple form, that asks if you're sure you want to submit it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#myform").on('submit', function(e)
  {
      if (!confirm('Are you sure?')){
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      else {
        console.log("submitting...");
      }
   });
});
```

Submit form, hit "ok" to the "are you sure" prompt, form submits just fine.

--refresh the page, clean slate--

Submit form, hit cancel to the "are you sure" prompt. Form does not submit, as expected. Submit form again, hit "ok" to the "are you sure" prompt, form still does not submit, "submitting..." gets logged to console. From this point on, the form will never submit until I refresh the page and hit "ok" to the prompt the first time.

If I swap

> e.preventDefault();

with

> return false;

nothing changes, exact same behavior.

I'm completely stumped. What am I doing wrong?

edit:
Here's a jsFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/8ac3Lgzg/. The HTML and JavaScript in that fiddle are /exactly the same/ as the code I have in my project. The issue I describe above does NOT happen when run on jsFiddle, but does in my project.

Comment: Can you post a stack snippet or jsFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: Are you positive it does not submit? Have you checked the network requests log? This can be a backend issue. The code provided does not seem to contain any issues.

Comment: does your submit button have the name `submit`?

Comment: @atmd, the OP stated that the form submits on the first attempt just fine. I'm thinking this is a backend state issue.

Comment: @MaximKumpan 100% sure it does not submit at all. It's not a back-end issue.

Comment: @atmd No. <input type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: how can the backend stop a clientside submit? that doesn't make sense. the form submits ***to*** the backend

Comment: So it doesnt have a name. try giving it a name (but not 'submit') jquery has issues with forms with 'submit' as the name, as it gets confused with the submit method of the form, or the submit element inside the form

Comment: @atmd Just gave it the name "test", issue persists. Thanks for the suggestion though, I didn't know jQuery may have that issue.

Comment: how about putting `$("form#myform").submit()` in the else?

Comment: @atmd Infinite loop of "Are you sure?" prompts until you hit "cancel", issue persists.

Comment: Why are you using a double-negative conditional expression? This is a perfect example of where you should be doing `if(true){...}else{...}` not `if(!false){...}else{...}`, if there was no else, it would make more sense, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @vol7ron Was just the way I wrote it at the time. It doesn't affect the issue obviously but you are, in general, correct.

Comment: Your project might contain other javascript event listeners to the form submit. Check all the code that you have.

Comment: @jsdude yes, sorry to derail, but your fiddle works for me in FF, and since you can't reproduce it there, the community might not be able to help.  You'll have to provide more code in order to find the bug.  Which version of jQuery? Which doctype? Which browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly, here is a jsFiddle demonstrating it.  I literally copy and pasted, there must be some other javascript influencing the form somewhere on your page.

```
jsFiddle link below
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xbhvqvp7/1/

Also might be worth checking the in browser network logs to see if the form is actually being submitted

Comment: I posted a jsFiddle in the OP, explaining the code worked there but not in my project. The form is not being submitted at all (nothing in network log).

However, you make a point about other javascript that may be messing with it, which I'm looking into now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs due to a piece of code another developer on my team wrote that I was unaware of, that attaches to every form and caches it's onSubmit handler result. Because my form would return false upon failing validation, that result would be cached for the next attempted submission even if it passed validation.

Without wanting to break his code, my solution was to add an attribute to my form, "no-cache", and I updated his method to check for that attribute. This has solved my problem.

Thanks to everybody who helped, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score -2):

try this manner

```
function SendForm(){
    if (!confirm('Are you sure?')){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        console.log("submitting...");
        return true;
    }
}
```

put the function sendForm in the submit button like this

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return SendForm();" />
```

obviously not display anything on the console because when you submit the form, the browser reloads